# How do I render a partial for a view of a nested resource? - Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

This is my route:

```
scope ":username" do
  resources :feedbacks
end
```

I am on my `home/index.html.erb` view and I am trying to do this:

```
<%= render "feedbacks/form" %>
```

But this gives me this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"feedbacks", :format=>nil}):
    1: <%= form_for(@feedback) do |f| %>
    2:   <% if @feedback.errors.any? %>
    3:     <div id="error_explanation">
    4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@feedback.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this feedback from being saved:</h2>
  app/views/feedbacks/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_feedbacks__form_html_erb__3181571289116259961_2487495480'
  app/views/home/index.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_home_index_html_erb___397233383548615486_2487321620'
```

This is my rake routes for feedbacks:

```
      feedbacks GET    /:username/feedbacks(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
                POST   /:username/feedbacks(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
   new_feedback GET    /:username/feedbacks/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
  edit_feedback GET    /:username/feedbacks/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
       feedback GET    /:username/feedbacks/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
                PUT    /:username/feedbacks/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
                DELETE /:username/feedbacks/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
```

**Edit 1**

When I pass in the local instance variable `@feedback` like this: `<%= render "feedbacks/form", :local => @feedback %>` which is pulling from my `home controller`, where it is declared like this:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
        @users = User.all
        @feedback = Feedback.new
  end

end
```

I still get this error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"feedbacks", :format=>nil}
```

**Edit 2**

I also have a `users` resource specified in my routes file, that looks like this:

```
 resources :users

    scope ":username" do
      resources :feedbacks
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `form_for` can't find the correct route, this line suggests you don't have an instance variable `@feedback` set when trying to render that partial:

```
(No route matches {:controller=>"feedbacks", :format=>nil})
```

Notice there is no `:id` parameter in that hash (which is likely being passed to the router to generate the correct URL to submit the form to).

Do you define a `@feedback` somewhere in the controller action (preferable) or views you're using?  If you think you are, try the following above line 1 of your partial:

```
logger.info "feedback object: #{@feedback.inspect}"
```

**Edit**:

First of all, locals should be passed not as `:local => @feedback` but as:

```
:locals => {:variable_name_in_partial => value_for_variable_name}
```

Second of all, you are trying to access `@feedback` which is an instance variable accessible to views even if it's not passed explicitly (as long as it's set).  So as long as you set it in the `HomeController#index` method you don't need to pass it to any views locally.

Also, you are not using the correct syntax for rendering partials (wish I had noticed earlier!).

Change the following:

```
<%= render "feedbacks/form" %>
```

To this:

```
<%= render :partial => "feedbacks/form" %>
```

Comment: You may be right. This is what I see from the `logger.info`: `feedback object: #<Feedback id: nil, poster_id: nil, receiver_id: nil, content: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`

Comment: I updated the question to reflect something else that I tried.

Comment: That's the thing, I have declared `@feedback = Feedback.new` in the actions (in the `home` & `feedback` controllers) for the views I am calling that partial in. It still gives me that error, even when I use your syntax. Also, my syntax was right: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials  But I tried your syntax anyway and am still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you forgetting to pass in `:username`? Your route says `scope :username`

If I add a route like yours, open up the Rails console, `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` and run `feedbacks_path`, I get a routing error, but `feedbacks_path :username => 'bob'` works fine.

```
> feedbacks_path(:username => 'bob')
=> "/bob/feedbacks"
```

Comment: Hrmm...the issue with this is that the partial should be allowing me to create a new `feedback` (where I specify which `user`) is responsible for the feedback. So the form partial has two `user_id` fields, so not sure passing `:username => 'bob'` would work in this situation

Comment: Maybe you need a route to the resource outside of scope :username, then

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want scope?  What about a nested resource as per:

```
resources :users do
  resources :feedbacks
end
```

Also, I've had trouble when using controllers with plural names.  You might try renaming `FeedbacksController` to `FeedbackController`.

Comment: Can you explain to me the differences between scope and nested resources? Why might I want one, as opposed to the other?

Comment: Also, is there a Rails way I can handle the rename? I generated a scaffold and customized everything as I went along. So I can't just change the Controller name. I would have to change the routes, model name, controller name, all the paths, etc. Is there an easy way to do everything in one fell swoop? i.e. one command?

Comment: I updated the question with an Edit 2 at the end, that shows you more of my `routes.rb` file. i.e. I have `resources :users` above my `scope :username` in my routes file. Am I being redundant? Also, remember that what I want to achieve is I want my URLs to look like `mydomain.com/joe-blow/feedback/1234` where `joe-blow` is a `username` for `user = Joe`. That changes with each user, just like Twitter URLs. If you have a better suggestion, I would love to hear it. Thanks.

Comment: So you do want scope.  I've scaffolded this up and it works for me with a controller action like this:
     `def new
      @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
      @feedback = @user.feedbacks.build
    end`
Clearly this won't catch cases where no user parameter is given.

I wouldn't recommend replacing them all at once because on some occasions you will _want_ a plural.  Your IDE may have facility to find and replace across files (ideally with manual confirmation).