# With the route generated by the Vanity gem, what is the Rails route helper I can use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, url-routing

This is the route the `Vanity` gem generates:

```
controller :vanities do 
  match ':vname' => :show, :via => :get, :constraints => {:vname => /[A-Za-z0-9\-\+]+/}
end
```

This is the rake routes:

```
GET    /:vname(.:format)                       {:vname=>/[A-Za-z0-9\-\+]+/, :controller=>"vanities", :action=>"show"}
```

How do I use the Rails link helper to link directly to URL `mydomain.com/vname`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my head (sorry, I don't really have the time to test it right now):

```
controller :vanities do 
  match ':vname' => :show, :via => :get, :constraints => {:vname => /[A-Za-z0-9\-\+]+/}, :as => :vanity
end
```

which you would use like this:

```
vanity_path(:vname => "marcamillion")
```

Comment: DUDE!!! You are on FIRE tonight. Thanks much. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you, thank you, thank you :)

Comment: Funny, mornings usually aren't my thing ;-)

Comment: Btw Mr. Fireman, how about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394701/how-do-i-render-a-partial-for-a-view-of-a-nested-resource-rails-3-1  :)