# How do I get my Rails 3.1 app to accept routes with an '@' symbol in the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have already setup the route file to include the username, via the `Vanity` gem.

However, now I can do just one specific URL - i.e. their username.

So the route generated by the gem looks like this:

```
  controller :vanities do 
    match ':vname' => :show, :via => :get, :constraints => {:vname => /[A-Za-z0-9\-\+]+/}
  end
```

So say someone registers with the username `test`, the system will automagically create their `vname` based on their username. But what happens if they go to `mydomain.com/@test`, I want them to end up at the same route as if they just went to `/test`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow an optional @ at the beginning of your vanity name with:

```
controller :vanities do 
  match ':vname' => :show, :via => :get, :constraints => {:vname => /@?[A-Za-z0-9\-\+]+/}
end
```

You would then have to strip the @ in your controller action, like this:

```
params[:vname].gsub!(/\A@/, '')
```

**Update**

If you want the replacement done in all your controllers, you can do it in a `before_filter` in your `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :rename_vanity

  def rename_vanity
    params[:vname].gsub!(/\A@/, '') if params[:vname]
  end
end
```

Comment: I know how to add it into the constraints for my vanity name. The issue is, when someone registers, they will not specify `@username` in their `username` field, nor do I want them to. I just want them to register with `test`, and they can do `mydomain.com/test` as well as `mydomain.com/@test`. So essentially what I want to do is have the user just register with a regular string captured by the RegEx `[A-Za-z0-9]`, but I want the router to automagically handle `@` prefixes on the URLs.

Comment: Btw, one way I tried doing this was upon new user creation, I created two vanities per user - and one with the `@` and one without. Then I added the `\@` exception to the constraints in the `vanities` controller. But that didn't work, because the Vanity gem only expects one vanity URL per user. So that never worked properly.

Comment: @marcamillion I don't understand, I believe I told you exactly how to do that. Modify the regexp in your routes and put the code that modifies the params at the beginning of the `show` action in `app/controllers/vanities_controller.rb`. Just register your users without the @ and it'll get handled automatically in the routes. We're talking about this gem, right? https://github.com/jaustinhughey/vanities.git

Comment: @Benoit-Garet sorry, you are absolutely right. I misread your answer. I thought you were just telling me how to accept the `@` in the vname, which I had already done. But one issue I am having with this solution is that the following URL does not work: `/@test/feedbacks/`, where `/test/feedbacks/` does. And  yes, we are talking about that gem.

Comment: I know one way is to put `params[:vname].gsub!(/\A@/, '')` in all the controllers and substitute the parameter for the correct one, but that hardly seems DRY. Is there another way?

Comment: Kewl...that looks great. By the way, any thoughts on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396104/with-the-route-generated-by-the-vanity-gem-what-is-the-rails-route-helper-i-can

Answer (score 0):

The `@` symbol is a reserved character in URLs, and must be percent-encoded (as `%40`) when used outside the particular context `@` is reserved for. The URL `mydomain/@test` simply isn't valid.

Comment: You're perfectly right, the browsers don't seem very picky though. I tested my answer with firefox and it worked without complaining.

Comment: This may be 'right', but why does http://www.twitter.com/@marcgayle work then? I want that functionality. I don't want to be perfect from a standards perspective. I just want that functionality.

Comment: I didn't know that twitter URLs accepted the @ symbol. I'm only familiar with the behavior of links breaking with misuse of characters. I don't know why this is an exception, although I'd speculate it's because the reserved use is esoteric enough that 'misuse' can be ignored safely. (I couldn't actually find what the 'proper' reserved use should be after several minutes of searching.)